# Issue with task scheduling and ordering

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I am using MS Project 2010 and trying to align four tasks correctly when importing into a master project. I created my template and the dates are correct, but when entering as a subproject into the master project the dates change. The scenario has task 1, task 2, task 3 and task 4. Task 4 needs to be manually scheduled and task 1, 2 and 3 need to be before task 4, but they need to be as late as possible. So I set 1, 2 and 3 to be as late as possible but I set them all as predecessors to task 4. When importing as a subproject, it moves 1,2 and 3 to the very end of the master project, after task 4. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,2, & 3 should be auto-scheduled. 4 Should be manual-scheduled.

Drop all current predecessors for these. Then make 4 a predecessor of each of 1,2 & 3, using a S-F constraint.

You don't need to set "Finish as late as possible".

Now when you manually reschedule 4, all the others will "follow" it and butt up against it to the left. It is common to think that "predecessor" means "before", but for MS-Project scheduling it means "timing relies on". Because you are saying that the timing of 1,2 & 3 relies on the timing of 4, 4 has to be the predecessor and you use the constraint type to indicate *how* they all rely on 4.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!